# How to compute the distance using samples from a smartphone accelerometer?

Tags: algorithm, accelerometer, physics, smartphone

If you have a list of sample values in coordinates from accelerometer.

```
accel[0]= {accelX0, accelY0, accelZ0}
...
accel[t]= {accelXt, accelYt, accelZt}
...
accel[tMax] = {accelXmax, accelYmax, accelZmax}
```

where t is a timestamp.
If the user make a short and fast movement towards a direction, is there a way to understand which direction he has taken and how much distance has been covered between 0 and tMax?
Do I have to integrate two times along each axis and choose the maximum result? 
I wouldn't need a particular precision and accuracy, just an generic value to make tests in real life. I wouldn't use GPS.
I'm not using a specific language or OS, I'm just interested in the algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

Integrating the acceleration vector once will give you the velocity, a second integration will give you the distance (Better use Runge-Kutta methods or similar).

If you walk 10 meters, stop, turn 90 degrees clock-wise, walk another 10 meters, the accelerometer can't tell that you yawed for example. To get the direction you'd need to sensor-fuse* the accelerometer measurements with measurements from the phone's gyro sensor and preferably with the magnetometer's measurements as well.

Note that these sensors are horribly inaccurate and are not suited for navigation, results will drift very quickly.

*Search for `IMU sensor fusion` (Inertial measurement unit), `6 DOF sensor fusion` (Without magnetometer or 9 with it).

Comment: With Runge-Kutta methods you  have to use some values at half timesteps... right? How would you do that if you don't have an analytical formula but measurements instead? Interpolation?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to integrate the acceleration vector (3D) two times vs "time".

For each measurement calculate:

> velocity := acc * delta_t
>
> distance := velocity * delta_t

And *sum* all distances. This gives you the overall distance moved.

delta_t is the time interval between two measurements. You might take the average interval of "time to next measurement" and "time to previous mesurement" if your mesurements are not sampled equidistant in time (i.e. not at regular time intervalls)

All calculations are done in 3D (i.e. for x,y,z components in parallel)

Answer (score 1):

The solution to your problem involves tow separate parts you have to deal with:

1. converting acceleration to distance
2. compensating for the limitations of a digital accelerometer.

   `Acceleration to distance`: this is the easy one - just integrate twice over time:
3. choose an interval (like 10ms, 20ms etc) and collect data from accelerometer once every interval; this is your DT.
4. do the math:

   sample code:

   ```
   while(1)
   {
      start  = getTimeinMS();

      velocity += acceleration *DT;
      displacement += velocity *DT;

      stop = getTimeinMS()

      While (stop-start < DT)
      {
         usleep(100) 
      }

   }
   ```

   Dealing with a digital accelerometer: this second part is a little trickier. You have to understand and compensate for two things:
5. Accelerometers are very noisy devices
6. Inertia is not your friend; let me explain - if you plot the accelerometer output you will notice that a left to right movement will bee a sin wave. A movement left-right-left will also be a sin wave. And you have no easy way of knowing when you stopped moving left-right and started right left. I'll assume you don't want that and are looking for simple displacement of a left - right movemet (or right - left, same logic).

If you understand and accept what I said so far you only have to deal with the accelerometer noise - not a very hard task since you can find loads of information and examples about digital filters. You can start off with a [rolling average filter](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Averages/Simple_moving_average) and implement a something more fancy later, if needed.

Hope this helps.